# How to get the openNMS nodes using python?

Tags: python, opennms

I am new to python and api , i have a openNMS server running and i need to get all the nodes that are on it. I have see through https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opennms-client/0.3 and i tried using it .. but the module  `len(c.get_nodes())`
gives me error saying

```
http://localhost:8980 (admin) <Response [200]>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "opennms.py", line 11, in <module>
    k = c.get_nodes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opennms_client/opennms_client.py", line 99, in get_nodes
    response = self.__request__(url).json()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 805, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Can someone please guide ??